# TypeError: utils.requestSendSMSPermission is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a function `requestSendSMSPermission` in `PermissionManager` which is in utils directory.

PermissionManager.js

```
module.export = {
  requestSendSMSPermission: async function() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.SEND_SMS
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  }
};
```

I have imported this in my component and trying to call this

```
var utils = require("../utils/PermissionManager.js");
utils.requestSendSMSPermission()
```

I am getting below error, can anyone suggest what is the cause of it and how I can fix it ?

```
D:\React Native\application\ui\CreateSMS.js:170 TypeError: utils.requestSendSMSPermission is not a function
    at CreateSMS._onPress (D:\React Native\application\ui\CreateSMS.js:138)
    at CreateSMS.proxiedMethod (D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-proxy\modules\createPrototypeProxy.js:44)
    at Object.onPress (D:\React Native\application\ui\CreateSMS.js:90)
    at Object.touchableHandlePress (D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\TouchableOpacity.js:129)
    at Object._performSideEffectsForTransition (D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:746)
    at Object._receiveSignal (D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:664)
    at Object.touchableHandleResponderRelease (D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:433)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:130)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:166)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (D:\React Native\application\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:169)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 1, it should be `module.exports`

Comment: Ah good catch. Thanks :) Why atom doesn't enough intelligent for these kinda errors :/